# creating a class in C#, use of unassigned variable

Tags: c#

I recieve a "use of unassigned varable in   InfoPeople". I am not sure why, my class is set up as the example in the textbook. Could someone shed a little light on this. Thanks.

```
  class personInfo
    {
        public string fName;
        public string lName;
        public int personID;
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            personInfo InfoPeople;
            InfoPeople.fName = "jeff";
            Console.WriteLine("the fName is: " + " " + InfoPeople.fName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @lukas - I'm just wondering where did you assume he was doing C++?  Given that he used `Console.WriteLine` there is not a single instance of that in C++.  If it was a joke it was really bad.

Comment: personInfo InfoPeople; This is common mistake of pepole form C++ background

Comment: @lukas - Read the entire code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't initialised your instance:

```
personInfo InfoPeople = new personInfo();
```

I would try and conform to C# style type/casing conventions:

```
PersonInfo infoPeople = new PersonInfo();
```

Comment: Thanks. I kinka thought that what it might be, but followed the syntax char by char in the book.

Answer (score 5):

You need to `new` your object instance like this:

```
personInfo InfoPeople = new personInfo();
```

That's just the C# syntax for creating new object instances.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't work because `InfoPeople` is a variable that holds a reference to a `personInfo`, but you never actually created a `personInfo`.

Fix it by saying:

```
personInfo InfoPeople = new personInfo();
```

---

By the way, your naming convention isn't very conventional. People generally *PascalCase* class names and *camelCase* variables. Try to follow that convention so that your code is easier to understand.

Answer (score 4):

*In C#, you **must** assign a value to a local variable before it is used* -- local variables do not default to anything (not even the default value of the type!).

As others have pointed out, the correct solution is likely to use a `new personInfo()`. However, just assigning `null` to the `InfoPeople` variable (above where it is used) will get rid of the compile-time error (and get a `NullReferenceException` at run-time ;-)

(That is, the compiler error has nothing to do with `InfoPeople` containing an "invalid" value -- it only cares that *some value* has been previously assigned.)

Happy coding.

---

Extra tip:

```
// C# allows one to instantiate a new object
// and assign members at the same time.
personInfo InfoPeople = new personInfo {
    fName = "jeff",
};
```

Answer (score 2):

change you first line in main() function as below. You specified the object type with "`personInfo InfoPeople`" statement but did not allocate memory. When you do that with 'new()' keyword, it actually creates object in memory, and that is what the error for.

```
personInfo InfoPeople = new personInfo()
```

Comment: You don't need to bring references to memory into this.

Answer (score 1):

You declare the local variable of type `personInfo` named `InfoPeople`, but you don't assign a value to it before trying to use it. The compiler can prove this and therefore it complains. Simple enough.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I was going to delete the answer because it doesn't really add anything above the others, but... yes, I 'm sure. Do you have another opinion?

Comment: @Jon I guess my objection is that the user's problem is more that they didn't create a new object instance. I agree that all it takes to make the compiler happy is to assign any object instance, a new one, a pre-existing one, or even null. So your answer is the most direct.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: As you say, I 've answered the "why does the compiler complain" question, and not the (unvoiced) "how should I fix that" question. Anyhow there's at least one person so far who believes the answer isn't helpful -- more reason to delete it.

Comment: +1 (Why is this a -1?) It correctly answers the compiler error message -- a fact that many of the "how should I fix it" replies fail to address. It could be expanded, sure, but it is terse and direct.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, @pst: pst's answer (which I just now read and upvoted) is simply better though.

Answer (score 1):

Have to instantiate an instance of personInfo

```
  class personInfo
{
    public string fName;
    public string lName;
    public int personID;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        personInfo InfoPeople = new personInfo();
        InfoPeople.fName = "jeff";
        Console.WriteLine("the fName is: " + " " + InfoPeople.fName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set InfoPeople to a new instance of personInfo:

personInfo InfoPeople = new personInfo();

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to instantiate that as new?

Answer (score 0):

"New personInfo" you have to instantiate the object from the class